# Problem returning properties to Class list from SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

I am try to query a SQL server using Dapper and get it to return a list of class objects with the column values as the matching properties for each object. I have a class called LeaveInfo with the following properties:

ID, Name, Date_, Leave, TDY, Appointments, Unavailable

and a SQL Table with matching columns, except Name. My code for the query is:

```
    public List<LeaveInfo> getLeaveInfo(string id, string date)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectStr("Schedules")))
        {
            return connection.Query<LeaveInfo>("dbo.LeaveCalendar_GetLeave @ID, @Date_", 
                new { ID = id, Date_ = date }).ToList();

            //return connection.Query<Person>("dbo.Personnel_GetShift @Shift_", new { Shift_ = shift_ }).ToList();
            //return connection.Query<Truck>("dbo.Trucks_GetTrucks").ToList();
        }
    }
```

SQL Procedure being called:

```
Create Procedure LeaveCalendar_GetLeave
    @ID     VARCHAR(2),
    @Date_  Date
As
Begin
    Set NoCount on  

    Select * from LeaveCalendar
    Where ID = @ID and Date_ = @Date_
End
```

Instead of returning all of the columns it only returns ID and Date_.
The commented out code are two similar queries that do the same thing and work exactly right, returning all property values of their respective classes.

I have queried it manually in SQL server

```
    Select * from LeaveCalendar
    Where ID = 54 and Date_ = '20191011'
```

for instance..
and it works fine there. So I have two other queries that work and as far as I can tell no errors with the SQL portion. I am not sure where the disconnect is occurring at this point.

I checked the property names to make sure they are aligning with the column names. Not only do they, but I have two procedures to add and delete information, to the same table using the same values, that also work.

So I can add and delete information just not check it from within the application...

Edit:

Apologies for the late additions and thank you for the time you all took to help. Unfortunately I found a syntax error elsewhere that resolved my issues, it's a wonder what fresh eyes will do for you...

It doesn't seem I can delete my question despite the trivial root cause.

Comment: You can use dynamic as well.

Comment: Please show us your model class and the attributes in your database table. The disconnect might behappening because of incorrect mapping between your class properties and column names.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public List<LeaveInfo> getLeaveInfo(string id, string date)
  {
            using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectStr("Schedules")))
            {
                var param = new DynamicParameters();
                param.Add("@ID", id, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
                param.Add("@Date_", date, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
                return connection.Query<LeaveInfo>("dbo.LeaveCalendar_GetLeave", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();                

                //return connection.Query<Person>("dbo.Personnel_GetShift @Shift_", new { Shift_ = shift_ }).ToList();
                //return connection.Query<Truck>("dbo.Trucks_GetTrucks").ToList();
            }
}
```